# Last loop in for()?

Tags: javascript

I have been struggling with this for a while:

```
for( var key in obj ){
    blah.blah()
    if(choice){
         doThis();
    }
}
```

How can I call `doThis()` only at the last item? Since I don't have a counter, `i`, I can't determine which is the last item.

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't use an interator `i`?

Comment: I am looping through an object. And `i` isn't defined in `for()` :(

Comment: Is there any reason you need to call `doThis` _within_ the loop?  The value of `key` will be the value of the last key when the loop is finished, you know, since you used `var` instead of `let`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First off, keys don't come in any guaranteed order.  By specification, the keys are unordered.  If you really wanted to do something with the last key you got, you could do so like this;

```
var lastkey;
for( var key in obj ){
    lastkey = key;
    blah.blah()
}
if(choice){
    // use lastkey if you want
    doThis();
}
```

Comment: +1 Nice use of `lastKey` because that will work if `var` is changed to `let` where just using `key` itself after the loop relies on the lack of block scope with `var`.

Answer (score 1):

With the caveat that jfriend00 mentioned in his answer that keys do not come in a guaranteed order, here is the most general transformation to augment:

- an arbitrary for-loop
- an arbitrary while-loop
- an arbitrary callback-based iterator like `[].forEach`

In the core of the loop block, our variable `isLast` will be `true` if it's the last, or `false` if it isn't:

```
var toDo = function(){};
forOrWhile(...) {
    toDo(false);
    toDo = function(isLast) {
        // blah.blah(); console.log('visited key '+key+' with value '+obj[key]+' where isLast='+isLast)
    };
}
toDo(true)
```

(If you need to capture the value of the iterator, you will need to put it in a closure as usual in javascript (Google for javascript for loop closure). You would get this for free if it was an Array, then you could use `[].map(function(){...})` or `.forEach(function(){...})`, and this is why frameworks's `foreach(object)` equivalents are useful; they will also usually filter out "prototype garbage" with [.hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty).)

Answer (score 0):

The code you've given would be translated to:

```
for( var key in obj ){
    blah.blah()
}
doThis();
```

If this doesn't work, please explain why in your question.